# Find the area of a parametric curve using Greens Theorem

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, area, greens-theorem

Given the curve $\vec\alpha(t)=(\cos(t),\sin(t)\cos(t))$ for $\frac {-\pi 
}2\le t \le \frac {\pi }2$

I am asked to find the volume so I need

$$\frac {\delta Q}{\delta x}-\frac {\delta P}{\delta y}=1$$ wich can be done with $\vec F=(y,2x)$ to get $\iint_C dA$

Now I am not sure on how to put the integral in terms of t, could someone explain?

Comment: When trig functions are involved, it's almost always better to use $\vec F = \frac12(-y,x)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use $P=0$ and $Q = x$. Then, if we let $C = \partial \Omega$, then 
$$
\begin{split}
\iint_\Omega dA
 &= \iint_\Omega \left(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}
                      - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\right)dA \\
 &= \int_{\partial \Omega} P(x,y) dx  + Q(x,y)dy \\
 &= \int_C xdy \\
 &= \int_{t=-\pi/2}^{t=\pi/2} x(t) dy(t) \\
 &= \int_{t=-\pi/2}^{t=\pi/2} x(t) y'(t) dt
\end{split}
$$
Can you finish this?